# how does GestureDetector work with canvas.draw circle custom paint

Tags: android, flutter, api, gesturedetector, custom-painting

```
GestureDetector(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: InteractiveViewer(
                    transformationController: viewTransformationController,
                    minScale: 0.2,
                    maxScale: 200.2,
                    child: Plotkhan(
                      recognizer: tapGestureRecognizer,
                      indexofitem: indexofitems,
                      height: 400.0,
                      data: _items
                          .map((e) => Point(num.parse(e['x'].toString()),
                              num.parse(e['y'].toString())))
                          .toList(),
                      gridSize: const Offset(1.0, 1.0),
                      style: PlotStyles(
                        pointRadius: 3.0,
                        trace: true,
                        outlineRadius: 1.0,
                        primary: Colors.white,
                        secondary: Colors.orange,
                        textStyle: const TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 8.0,
                          color: Colors.blueGrey,
                        ),
                      ),
                      padding:
                          const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(40.0, 12.0, 12.0, 40.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

its a dot connecting app which I have a list of diagram with offset that implements  `canvas.drawcircle` from list. I researched so didn't find any thing related `GestureDetector` with `canvas.drawcircle`. the rest of function is working well if I set function on any button, but don't know how to achieve function with `canvas.drawcircle`.

Comment: if user click next index of(canvas.drawCircle) it should draw line with the previous one circle, for now i am doing this with manually int variable and calling function from button its working well, but i want to do it with gesture detector of canvas.draw circle,

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
      int ins = i + 1;

      Offset point = _scalePoint(points[i], size);

      // canvas.drawCircle(point, style.pointRadius, circlePaint);
      canvas.drawCircle(point, style.pointRadius, circlePaint);

      if (style.outlineRadius > 0.0) {
        canvas.drawCircle(
          point,
          style.pointRadius,
          outlinePaint,
        );
      }

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < indexofitem; i++) {
        bool isLastPoint = (i + 1) == points.length;
        var firstPoint = _scalePoint(points[i], size);
        if (!isLastPoint) {
          var secondPoint = _scalePoint(points[i + 1], size);
          canvas.drawLine(
            firstPoint,
            secondPoint,
            traceLinePaint,
          );
        }
        if (isLastPoint && style.traceClose && points.length > 2) {
          var secondPoint = _scalePoint(points[0], size);
          canvas.drawLine(
            firstPoint,
            secondPoint,

Comment: your code must be in code style and please read your full sentence to correct your grammar.

Comment: my grammar isnot good

Comment: I edited your post bro.

Comment: thanks for help, it is my first post, did you have any solution of my problem